# ASM TraceClassVisitor output file is error

Tags: java, bytecode

When I learn the usage of org.objectweb.asm.util.TraceClassVisitor, I will output a file from the conversion result, and use ByteArrayInputStream to read the byte of classwrite and output file1. However, when I use javap instruction to view bytecode, the file will report an error and file1 can be viewed normally.I need your help.

dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0'
    implementation 'org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0'
    implementation 'org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0'
    implementation 'org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0'
    implementation 'org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0' }
```

the code like this.

```
fun main() {
    val classWriter = ClassWriter(0)
    // 使用 TraceClassVisitor
    val traceClassWriter =
        TraceClassVisitor(classWriter, PrintWriter("asm_example/files/TraceClassVisitorDemo.class"))
    traceClassWriter.visit(
        Opcodes.V1_7,
        Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC + Opcodes.ACC_INTERFACE + Opcodes.ACC_ABSTRACT,
        "part2/TraceClassVisitorDemo",
        null,
        "java/lang/Object",
        null
    )
    traceClassWriter.visitSource("TraceClassVisitorDemo.class", null)
    traceClassWriter.visitField(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC+ Opcodes.ACC_FINAL + Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "className", "Ljava/lang/String;", null, "").visitEnd()
    traceClassWriter.visitField(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC+ Opcodes.ACC_FINAL + Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "classVersion", "I", null, 50).visitEnd()
    traceClassWriter.visitMethod(
        Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC + Opcodes.ACC_ABSTRACT,
        "getTraceInfo",
        "()Ljava/lang/String;",
        null,
        null
    ).visitEnd()
    traceClassWriter.visitEnd()

    ClassOutputUtil.byte2File("asm_example/files/TraceClassVisitorDemo1.class", classWriter.toByteArray())
}
```

when I use javap instruction to view bytecode, the file will report an error and file1 can be viewed normally.

**javap -v TraceClassVisitorDemo.class**

```
错误: 读取asm_example/files/TraceClassVisitorDemo.class的常量池时出错: unexpected tag at #1: 101
```

when I change PrintWriter("asm_example/files/TraceClassVisitorDemo.class") into PrintWriter(System.out)。The output information is as follows：

```
// class version 51.0 (51)
// access flags 0x601
public abstract interface com.andoter.asm_example.part2/TraceClassVisitorDemo {

  // compiled from: TraceClassVisitorDemo.class

  // access flags 0x19
  public final static Ljava/lang/String; className = ""

  // access flags 0x19
  public final static I classVersion = 50

  // access flags 0x401
  public abstract getTraceInfo()Ljava/lang/String;
}
```

Comment: As you can see when directing it to `System.out`, the `TraceClassVisitor` produces a human readable representation, not a class file. Since you are also aware that `toByteArray()` produces the actual class file, it’s not clear why you think that the purpose of `TraceClassVisitor` was to create another redundant class file.

Comment: One of the parameters in traceclassvisitor is printer, so I want to try to output the form of a file, but I'm puzzled why javap doesn't recognize it

Comment: When you direct the printer to a file instead of `System.out`, it’s still the same text content you saw on the console. Any text editor can show you that. The tool `javap` is for parsing real class files.